# Entity framework adding properties to my class (over my head)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties, fluent, derived-class

I'm trying to create a datastructure with entity framework to basically store property values of my objects. I want users to add properties to a class at runtime. The properties can be of different datatypes. (string/int/float etc..)

So I thought I needed some tables/classes as defined in the image below.
[image: Tables]
So my Object class contains a list of properties that are of a type defined in de propertydefinition class.

One hard thing is that values are stored in the table of the datatype of the propertie. (So a conditional foreignKey?)

Please give me some pointers on how to implement this by using Fluent API. Or other ideas on this subject. (I guess I won't be the first ;)

Werner

Comment: Why do you want to store it using EF? This could be implemented more easyly with a NoSQL database, directly storing the objects serialized as JSON

Comment: You shouldn't build a database consisting entirely of this EAV model. EAV should be used in exceptional cases when there is no alternative. Use entities with fixed properties. I can't imagine customers should amend *each* entity by their own properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)

This helped me solve my "Table Per Type" question. I now have:

```
public abstract class PropertyBase
{
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TextProperty : PropertyBase
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class IntProperty : PropertyBase
{      
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

In My Database Context I added:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyBase>()
            .HasKey(p => p.PropertyID)
            .ToTable("Properties");                    

        modelBuilder.Entity<IntProperty>()
            .ToTable("IntProperties");

        modelBuilder.Entity<TextProperty>()
            .ToTable("TextProperties");
```

The different types of properties (sub classes) are now stored in separate tables. The main abstract class contains all the other info. This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The EF entity model cannot be changed during Runtime (or at least is not designed for). You could use an infrastructure to store propertyname/propertyvalye with EF but I think is not the right choice (you lose most of the functionalities).

The best choice could be a NoSQL db, ADO.Net or, if only some objects can be personalized and other are fixed you could store the personalizable objects in XML/JSON in a text field.